# What is the plastic gauze / grid in a bonsai replanting kit for?

Tags: bonsai

I bought a bonsai replanting kit and its got this plastic grid / gauze in it. I could not work our what its for. Is it to cover the hole at the bottom of the pot to stop dirt falling our or has it another use?

I've attached an image to show what i'm talking about.

[image: Photo of plastic grid thing]

Answer (score 1):

Yes the mesh is meant for covering the drainage holes. You can put it on the inside on the hole, and attach it with wire, like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NumZ79JxgT0). You prevent with this that too much soil is lost through the hole.